# Is there support for the RabbitMQ mandatory flag in MassTransit

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I would like to get an exception when sending to a RabbitMQ exchange using MassTransit if the message is not delivered to any queues. It looks like the RabbitMQ mandatory flag could be used for something like this, but I have not been able to find any way to set this using MassTransit. Is this supported?

My code:

```
var personSendEndpoint = busControl.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri($"rabbitmq://localhost/{personQueueName}")).Result;

// An exception should occur on the following call if the message is not delivered to any queue
personSendEndpoint.Send(new PersonUpdated() { Name = "Dorian Gray", Key = Guid.NewGuid() });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Mandatory` flag, but there isn't a cute extension methods to do it for you. Basically, you do as shown below:

```
await endpoint.Send(new PersonUpdate(...), context =>
{
    (context as RabbitMqSendContext).Mandatory = true;
});
```

And that will set the flag telling RabbitMQ to throw an exception if no bindings for the exchange exist.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm now setting the mandatory flag, but not getting a .Net exception from the send call (I checked the exchange I am posting to has no bindings). Is the RabbitMQ exception getting supressed by MassTransit? Is there some way to test if the send succeded? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you awaiting the call the Send(), every method in MassTransit is async so you'll need to await the method return if you want to see the exception.

Comment: Yes, I am awaiting the send. That doesn't seem to be it.